# Is there a pythonic solution for cross-platform (windows-mac-linux) SCrypt?

Tags: python, hash, cross-platform, bcrypt, scrypt

I've been searching for it whole night and even cross-platform bcrypt python library is not found. Do I have to switch to c library and wrote my own wrapper around it or is there other way?

Comment: py-bcrypt is cross-platform. I haven't checked py-scrypt yet, but it looks to be cross-platform as well.

Comment: @Blender  Definitely will check it out but little googling showed people often having trouble with compiling respective b/s-crypts libraries on windows so pure python implementation would be more welcome.